Import "dotenv/config"; not working
I was following the official tutorials with VS Code and got stuck when I tried to import 'dotenv/config'. It said 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'. What should I do? Thank you in advance.

you might not have the module installed.  npm i dotenv

I did install the latest dotenv and it still had the error. The only way it worked was to use import dotenv from "dotenv"; dotenv.config(); But I would like to know why I couldn't use the suggested way to do it.

What was the suggested way?

It uses " import "dotenv/config" ". I want to do as same as it does. Didn't you encounter this error?

Is this using TypeScript? And you're running the program with esrun?

There is two syntax for importing modules in typescript (and js in general) depending on the module format CJS or the more recent ESM introduced by EcmaScript 6 (ES6).
Long story short:
based on the ES version used.

ES6 => Import
ES5 => required

So for dotenv as written in the readme
It would be either:
import 'dotenv/config'
or
require('dotenv').config();
The Solana labs use the first, just try to change by the later.
